# org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented error when trying to perform an action on an iOS native element

Tags: ios, macos, selenium, appium, appium-ios

Method has not yet been implemented error on performing an action (click, clear, send key etc) on a iOS native element. But findElement work just fine

Happening only for iOS, working fine for Android.

The current context is NATIVE_APP

Same code and device works perfectly fine on another machine.

```
DesiredCapabilities cap = new DesiredCapabilities();

cap.setCapability("platformName", "ios");

cap.setCapability("platformVersion", "9.2");

cap.setCapability("deviceName", "ipad");        

cap.setCapability("udid", <my device's  UDID>);     

cap.setCapability("app", "/Users/syscotester/Documents/APP/App.ipa");

WebDriver  driver = new IOSDriver<>(new URL("http://127.0.0.1:4724/wd/hub"),cap);
driver.findElement(By.xpath("//UIAWebView[1]/UIATextField[1]"));

elm.click();
```

Exception is on elm.click();line

It was working fine till yesterday; but suddenly stopped working.
Please help

The stack trace:

> Exception in thread "main" org.openqa.selenium.WebDriverException: Method has not yet been implemented (WARNING: The server did not provide any stacktrace information)
>   Command duration or timeout: 25 milliseconds
>   Build info: version: '2.53.1', revision: 'a36b8b1', time: '2016-06-30 17:37:03'
>   System info: host: 'TVMATP285575M', ip: '10.155.190.189', os.name: 'Mac OS X', os.arch: 'x86_64', os.version: '10.11.5', java.version: '1.8.0_101'
>   Driver info: io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver
>   Capabilities [{app=/Users/syscotester/Documents/APP/UOMQASQ.ipa, networkConnectionEnabled=false, databaseEnabled=false, deviceName=Parvathy's ipad, platform=MAC, showIOSLog=true, desired={app=/Users/syscotester/Documents/APP/UOMQASQ.ipa, showIOSLog=true, platformVersion=9.2, platformName=iOS, udid=da85ce3eac13bf4d19b627ee3c1ac02a2b9a2bfe, deviceName=Parvathy's ipad}, platformVersion=9.2, webStorageEnabled=false, locationContextEnabled=false, browserName=, takesScreenshot=true, javascriptEnabled=true, platformName=iOS, udid=da85ce3eac13bf4d19b627ee3c1ac02a2b9a2bfe}]
>   Session ID: 8d5cb461-e7ab-4745-ab6e-1f80d916e34b
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
>       at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
>       at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
>       at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.createThrowable(ErrorHandler.java:206)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.ErrorHandler.throwIfResponseFailed(ErrorHandler.java:158)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebDriver.execute(RemoteWebDriver.java:678)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileDriver.execute(DefaultGenericMobileDriver.java:51)
>       at io.appium.java_client.AppiumDriver.execute(AppiumDriver.java:1)
>       at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSDriver.execute(IOSDriver.java:1)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.execute(RemoteWebElement.java:327)
>       at io.appium.java_client.DefaultGenericMobileElement.execute(DefaultGenericMobileElement.java:46)
>       at io.appium.java_client.MobileElement.execute(MobileElement.java:1)
>       at io.appium.java_client.ios.IOSElement.execute(IOSElement.java:1)
>       at org.openqa.selenium.remote.RemoteWebElement.click(RemoteWebElement.java:85)
>       at Tester.main(Tester.java:26)

Answer (score 0):

I end up creating a new user account in MAC. 
Looks like the issue is with Appium. Cache was not properly getting deleted when I uninstall it (Move to trash. I am using dmg). 
But when I created a new user account and did all my settings/installation the native element started working.

The above is only a work around, that too a very cumbersome one. Please share if you have any other solutions.